# how to free shm memory after joblib fail

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, shared-memory, joblib

I have started python task that used joblib (sklearn GridSearchCV) and I stopped operation (Ctrl-C), after that it stopped on

```
^CProcess PoolWorker-42:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 102, in worker
task = get()
  File "/home/project/.virtualenvs/tripcase/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/pool.py", line 360, in get
    return recv()
KeyboardInterrupt
^CProcess PoolWorker-43:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 102, in worker
    task = get()
  File "/home/project/.virtualenvs/tripcase/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/pool.py", line 360, in get
    return recv()
KeyboardInterrupt
^CProcess PoolWorker-44:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 102, in worker
    task = get()
  File "/home/project/.virtualenvs/tripcase/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/pool.py", line 360, in get
    return recv()
KeyboardInterrupt
```

in the end I have killed father process and now I am stuck with files in /dev/shm
how to remove them safely?